# Geometric inequality in triangle with inradius

Tags: inequality, summation, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

I am trying to examine if the inequality $ab+bc+ca \ge 12Rr+ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}$ holds for a triangle. Since $ab+ca+ca \ge 4r(5R-r)$ (Bottema, p. 53) it is enough to prove $12r(2R-r) \ge a^2+b^2+c^2.$ I tried to use some other inequalities from Bottema but without any success. Any help?

Comment: To make sure I'm clear, as well as anybody else reading this, is $R$ is the triangle excircle or escribed circle radius and $r$ is the triangle incircle or inscribed circle radius? Note I got these triangle circle terms from [Incircle and excircles of a triangle](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle), but I believe other terms are sometimes used, such as circumscribed circles instead of escribed circles.

Comment: Inradius $r$ is the radius of the circle which is inscribed inside the triangle. Circumradius $R$ is defined as the radius of that circle which circumscribes (surrounds) the triangle

Comment: @JohnOmielan The notation for excircle radius is usually $r_a$ for the excircle touching $BC$. This is used in the wiki that you linked to. One way to remember why small $r$ is because of the similarity with incircle definition.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard notation we need to prove that:
$$ab+ac+bc\geq12\cdot\frac{abc}{4S}\cdot\frac{2S}{a+b+c}+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}$$ or
$$3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\geq18abc+(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(-a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c-3abc)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, since
$$3b-a-c>2b+a-c-a-c=2(b-c)\geq0,$$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(-a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c-3abc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(4a^2b+4ab^2-8abc-2a^3+2abc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(4ab(b-c-(c-a))-(a+b+c)(a-b)^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(4(a-b)(ac-bc)-(a+b+c)(a-b)^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3c-a-b)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-c)^2(3b-a-c))\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-b)^2(3b-a-c))=$$
$$=(a-b)^2(b+c-a)\geq0.$$